# Onclick Events in Titanium Require Waiting Several Seconds Between Clicks

Tags: javascript, titanium

I've got a mobile app written using Titanium SDK. There are various views that have click events. Some are assigned through the XML view using `onClick="functionName"`, and others are assigned using `$.viewId.addEventListener('click', function(){})`.

Either way, if I click on a view once, I have to wait for anywhere from five to forty five seconds before it will allow me to click on it to perform the function again. This is for all of the pages that use native views.

Clicking on a second different view works just fine, the first time. It's only when I click the same view a second time that I notice the delay.

The pages that use WebViews do not have this problem. So native Titanium is less responsive than WebViews with HTML and JavaScript.

This problem is present for both 12.1.0.RC and 12.2.1.GA.

Is this an intentional feature or a know bug in Titanium SDK?

How can I make the click events work for a second click more rapidly?

Comment: this sounds like a broken method of distinguishing clicks from touch-hold.

Comment: Actually, it sounds more like a rate limit is configured somewhere.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think so. I've got a button that allows the user to upload an image to my company's server, and I want them to be able to upload as many images as they need. So they click a button to open the camera, and it works. Then if they want another picture, they need to click the button again.

Comment: @Barmar Where are rate limits configured in a Titanium app? Or is this some feature built into the settings of iOS?

Comment: No idea. I didn't even know what Titanium was until I saw this question.

Comment: Android or iOS? There is no "cool-down" in the SDK as far as I know, just the normal phone delay in order to decide if it is a click, double click or singletap. So you could try to use `singletap` instead. You can also test the https://github.com/tidev/kitchensink-v2 app and go to `View - View events` and click on the view to get the events on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Click events:**

XML and JS event listener do the same thing. If you assign it in the XML/Alloy it will automatically add the `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` for you. So it takes less code to write the listeners. You can see that in the generated code in `Resources/android/alloy/controllers/`

**Delay:**

The phone has a "delay" to differentiate between tap, click, double click and so on. But there shouldn't be any delay in the SDK itself. What you can do if you need a faster click rate: use the `singletap` event (https://titaniumsdk.com/api/titanium/ui/view.html#events_singletap) instead of click.

A webview doesn't use native elements so the phone rules don't apply there. That's why a click is different in a webview.

Comment: Thank you. Using $.viewId.addEventListener('singletap', function(){}) solved it.